# .DLL error in Image Recognition using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll, keras

Getting .dll error when running the application which is built using keras(which uses TensorFlow as backend). Installed Virtual Studio C++ and also .dll files like msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll but still there is error.

**Error message is as below:**

```
PS C:\Users\dmutta> python E:\BMW_IMAGE_ANALYSIS\app.py  
Using TensorFlow backend.  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "E:\BMW_IMAGE_ANALYSIS\app.py", line 6, in <module> 
    from keras.preprocessing import image
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 186, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 196, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Is this the first time you're trying to run tensorflow in this machine/SO? It seems you didn't install everything properly. This sounds like a problem with blas in scipy. I suggest you try installing numpy and scipy from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thank you. I run tensorflow many times...I completed my application also but recently DNS server is installed in my lapy, from that time I am getting .dll error.